# virtual Y cable to sound card

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, audio-recording, audio-sync

is there a way to create virtual Y cables for my sound card hardware?  In other words, I need to create two virtual copies of the hardware sound card.

The reason is I have two programs that need to access the sound card at the same time.

Both programs will process captured samples (mic or line input) simultaneously, but only one program will play back at any given time via speaker out.

Does this make sense?

I experimented with snd-aloop but it didn't seem to do what I needed.  I believe this is possible perhaps using pulse, but ideally I'd like to just stick with something simple like snd-aloop.

Thanks, Matt.

Comment: PulseAudio should work. The default ALSA configuration (with dmix/dsnoop) should work.

Comment: Yes, forgot to update this topic, I was able to get what I needed using dmix/dsnoop.